# How can I create a report that shows me a count of how many times a value appears in a table?

Tags: sqlite

I have a very simple table that looks like this in SQL:

```
EnglishCount

0
1
2
1
3
4
6
1
2
```

Just one column with a value from 0 to 10.

What I would like to do is to create  a report that will show me this:

```
EC      Qty
1       3
2       2
3       1
4       1
6       1
```

Can someone give me a suggestion how I can achieve this. Note that I would like the value of EC to appear in order and only show a count where rows have an EnglishCount > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one correct approach:

```
SELECT
    EnglishCount AS EC,
    COUNT(*) AS Qty
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY EnglishCount
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    EnglishCount
```

Comment: Works very well.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
select EnglishCount as EC,count(*) as Qty from table group by EnglishCount;
```

If you want to order by the EnglishCount,

```
select EnglishCount as EC,count(*) as Qty from table group by EnglishCount order by EnglishCount;
```

If you want to order by the count,

```
select EnglishCount as EC,count(*) as Qty from table group by EnglishCount order by Qty;
```

Comment: How can I make this also order by the count value so it shows the total number of rows that have a count of 1 first?

Comment: @Alan see the last statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select EnglishCount as EC,count(*) as Qty from TableName where EnglishCount > 0 group by EnglishCount;
```

try this...

Comment: How can I make this also order by the count value so it shows the total number of rows that have a count of 1 first?

Comment: select EnglishCount as EC,count(*) as Qty from TableName where EnglishCount > 0 group by EnglishCount order by Qty;  try this